# Java delete database update panel

Tags: java, database

Everytime I delete something from my JButton it deletes in the database but my jpanel wont update... 
I wonder if there is an easy fix for this?

```
private void DeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    infLabel.setText(inform[2]);

    Connection connection = FlatFinder.getConnection();
    Statement selectStmt = null;
    try {
        selectStmt = connection.createStatement();
        Flat activeFlat = (Flat) AdminAll.getSelectedValue();
        String sql = String.format(
                "DELETE FROM `flats` WHERE flat_id = %d",
                activeFlat.getId()
        );
        selectStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    this.repaint();
}
```

This is my current code. Is there any easy solution to update the jpanel when I press the delete button?

Comment: Are you calling `repaint()` anywhere? The panel won't update unless you tell it to.

Comment: no I am pretty new to java... Where shall I call repaint? :) Can you give an example. Thanks

Comment: Assuming that this method is inside of your panel definition, just call `this.repaint()`. If it's not, you should have a variable representing the panel, in which case you would call something like `my_panel.repaint()`.

Comment: It is inisde MainPanel.java so I guess I should call this.repaint() but where in the code shall I put it? :)

Comment: After you've updated all of the content. Logically, that would just be at the end of the method.

Comment: I added an update where I placed it but it wont work

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually updating the content of the panel... What kind of change are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I have some information from an database in an Jlist and I can delete but the problem is everytime I delete something I have to restart the application for the JList to update, I am looking for an easy way to fix this :D thanks

Comment: You don't have any code that updates the `JList`. You need to write the code to reload that list. It sounds like you already have it in an initializer method, so just copy that and call it in here.

Comment: You said you have a `JList` that has the data in it, but you never update it in this code. Changing the database won't automatically update the `JList`; you have to tell it to update (and do the updating yourself).